# UItableview returns more row?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have done like

```
  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 {
    return 3;
}
```

tableview is in UITableViewStylePlain.but it shows correctly 3 data on 3 tableview cell.but after that there is empty tableview cells ...but when i declared UITableViewStyleGrouped, it shows only 3 tableview cells... perfectly...what i have to do disappear empty tableview cell
in UITableViewStylePlain..any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Your table contains 3 table cells and those cells beneath it are not empty table cells. The row seperators are just drawn based on the previous row height giving the impression that there are more cells than you actually specified.

You could set the separatorStyle of the table view to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone, either in code or in Interface Builder. But doing so disables the seperators all together, so you would have to draw some kind of separator yourself in your cells if you still wanted a grafical separation between the actual cells.

Another option would be to set the color of the separator to the color of the background of the table.

I myself would not worry about this if you're application has a standard table look, as it's default behaviour & users should be used to seeing that. Altough I must admit that I have set the separatorStyle to none in a previous project, because the table had a look that deviated from the standard table look. I did have to draw a fine separator line at the bottom in the table cell.